# Load files in sequential order

Tags: linux, files, sort, csh, sql

I need to load multiple files in my shell script with the same filename but appended in the front of each file name is YYMMDDPERSONNEL
Examples: 231102PERSONNEL and 230103PERSONNEL
There are many other files in the same directory so filenames are important in the sort.
I need to sort files to be loaded from the oldest to the newest.

Currently what I have is only designed to handle one file at a time.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some example file names and then the order you want those file names to be read in. Make sure to include all relevant edge cases (are all files from this century? What are the `****`?)

Comment: Also, do you _need_ to rely on the name or can you use the file's modification date instead?

Comment: Please put that extra information [in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/760865/edit), not in the comments, @teejay

Comment: Sorting in descending order would give you the youngest not oldest first

Comment: In an earlier version of your question you mentioned the need to uncompress files, is that no longer needed?

Comment: Correct, it is easy enough to uncompress them all, so I think I needlessly complicated the question. I am trying to focus on just loading more than one file at a time in this script.

Comment: Simply expanding the pattern `??????PERSONNEL*` (or `*PERSONNEL*`) would give you all the files in the correct order, assuming there are no files from the last century. Is this not what you want?  What are "the other files"? How is the [tag:csh] tag relevant to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Shell globs are expanded in lexical order by default and a lexical order in your case matches the chronological (*sequential*) order of your files as long as they're all from the same century (well from 1900 to 1999 for instance, ignoring the fact that the 20<sup>th</sup> century actually ran from 1901 to 2000).

With `zsh`:

```bash
set -o extendedglob
for f ( [0-9](#c6)PERSONNEL.sql.gz(N) ) gunzip < $f | your-sql-loader
```

(Or `[0-9](#c6)PERSONNEL.sql.gz(NOn)` if you need to `O`rder the files by `n`ame, in reverse (captital `o`) as you initially requested).

That assumes `your-sql-loader` can take its input from stdin. If it needs it to be passed as a filename argument:

```bash
for f ( [0-9](#c6)PERSONNEL.sql.gz(N) ) your-sql-loader <(gunzip < $f)
```

Or if that filename argument has to be regular file:

```bash
for f ( [0-9](#c6)PERSONNEL.sql.gz(N) ) your-sql-loader =(gunzip < $f)
```

Chances are you may just be able to do:

```bash
gunzip -dc -- [0-9](#c6)PERSONNEL.sql.gz | your-sql-loader
```

That is feed the concatenation of all the uncompressed contents of all the files sorted in reverse to `your-sql-loader`.

More generally, it's rare to ever have to store an uncompressed version of a file on disk. It's much better to uncompress it on the fly and feed it concurrently to whatever application consumes it.

You'd only need to uncompress it on disk (as is done with the `=(...)` approach above which gets the output of `gunzip` in a temp file) if the consumer application doesn't read the data sequentially (which would be surprising here if that's meant to be SQL).

If you really had to use (t)csh as the tag suggests which would be very surprising in this century, the equivalent assuming file names don't contain newline characters would be:

```bash
gunzip -dc -- "`ls -rd -- [0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]PERSONNEL.sql.gz`" | your-sql-loader
```

Where `ls -r` sorts the files by name in reverse; with `` "`...`" `` its output is retrieved and split into its non-empty line constituents.

Since `csh` has no equivalent of zsh's `[0-9](#c6)` or ksh's `{6}([0123456789])` to match 6 digits, we match each digit specifically and take the opportunity to be stricter in matching month and day numbers.

If you have files from the past century, you can define a custom sort order in zsh with either the `oe[code]` or `o+function` glob qualifiers.

```bash
[0-9](#c6)PERSONNEL.sql.gz(Noe['REPLY[1,0]=$(( 19 + ($REPLY[1,2] < 70) )'])
```

That is instruct zsh to order the glob based on the name of the file to which we've prepended either 20 or 19 depending on whether the first 2 digits make up a number that is more or less than 70 (you'll want to adjust the cut-off year based on your actual dataset; 1970 chosen here because that's the start of Unix epoch time).

Comment: since they mention "oldest to newest", shouldn't the default sort order already be ok? `(On)` would give newest to oldest.

Comment: Yes, but I initially incorrectly said descending order. The answer was correct to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple task, with pipelines.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*PERSONNEL.gz' -print | \
    sed -e 's%^./%%' | \
    sort | \
    xargs -r /bin/echo
```

Read the `man` pages.

Here's a quick overview:

- `find` prints a list of filenames to `STDOUT`
- `sed` makes it look nicer (changes `./231102PERSONNEL.gz` to `231102PERSONNEL.gz`)
- `sort` sorts the list.
- `xargs` puts as many files as will fit (see `xargs --show-limits </dev/null` for *your* limits) and repeats the "command" for the rest of the list
- `/bin/echo` is a placeholder.